# Spring JMS + WebSphere MQ client

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

I was trying to configure jms template to connect to WebSphere MQ. When using Websphere client jar, there are multiple options that were set like  MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING  etc for Queue's and PUT and GET options like MQC.MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID ,  MQC.MQGMO_WAIT, MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID etc.,.,

is there way to pass these option to JMS template ?

Answer (score 1):

These options are IBM MQ specific, so don't think they can be passed as it is to Spring. But some of these have a JMS equivalent available in Spring template.

`MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT` option means open queue for putting messages and is equivalent to JMS `createProducer` API.

`MQC.MQGMO_WAIT` option is equivalent to `receive(timeout)`

`MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID` - is equivalent to creating a consumer with a selector `"JMSCorrelatoinID=<your correlationid>"`

Comment: is there an sample that can be referred with the integration, tried to follow couple of samples but couldnt replicate the client jar functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one